# Regex stops at first match

Tags: python, regex-greedy

I am trying to capture both 'catwoman' and 'superman' but the match stops at the first instance. What can i do to capture both matches?

```
p3= re.compile(r"\w+(wo)?man")
t='what if catwoman and superman got married!'
r3=p3.search(t)
print(r3.group())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `re.findall` for [finding](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.findall) all matches. Also, you have to redefine regular expression.

Here is how it works:

```
p3 = re.compile(r'(\w+man)')
t = 'what if catwoman and superman got married!'
r3 = p3.findall(t) # 'findall' corrected originally misspelt 'finadll'
print(r3) # ['catwoman', 'superman']
```